# Lookup Column Keeps Returning as Undefined

Tags: 2013, javascript, lookup-column, jslink

I am getting a TypeError that I cannot figure out for the life of me.  I am unable to debug as my company forces IE11, and I do not understand its interface [I use Chrome, which I don't have access to].   The error states:

> TypeError: Unable to get property 'CurrentItem' of undefined or null reference

I am trying to override both at the Item level, and two fields which are lookup columns.  I cannot figure out why the **projCat** field and the **project** field are turning up null or undefined?

Here is the code:

```
(function(){

var itemCtx = {};
itemCtx.Templates = {};

itemCtx.Templates.Header = "<div id='container'><table><tr><td>Project Category</td><td>Project</td><td>Project Summary</td><td>Toolkit Compliance</td><td>Project Lead</td></tr>";
itemCtx.Templates.Item = ItemOverride;
itemCtx.Templates.Footer = "</table></div>";

itemCtx.BaseViewID = 1;
itemCtx.ListTemplateType = 100;

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(itemCtx);

})();

function ItemOverride(ctx) {

    var projCat = projectCat();
    var projSum = ctx.CurrentItem.Summary;
    var project = projectName();
    var projLead = ctx.CurrentItem.projLead[0].title;
    var projComp = ctx.CurrentItem.artCompliance;
    var html = "<tr class='content'><td><div id='projCat'>" + projCat + "</div></td><td>" + project + "</td><td>" + projSum + "</td><td>" + projComp + "</td><td>" + projLead + "</td></tr>";

        if (projCat == "Change Mangement") {
            $("div#projCat").addClass("cm");
        }

        else if (projCat == "Communications") {
            $("div#projCat").addClass("comms");
        }

        else if (projCat == "Modernization") {
            $("div#projCat").addClass("mod");
        }

        else if (projCat == "OBPI Support") {
            $("div#projCat").addClass("obpi");
        }


        else if (projCat == "Process Improvement") {
            $("div#projCat").addClass("pi");
        }

        else if (projCat == "Project Management Standardization"){
            $("div#projCat").addClass ("pms");
        }
    return html;

}



(function (){
     var overrideCtx = {};
     overrideCtx.Templates = {};

    /* alert("Override worked");*/

overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {
    "projCat" : {"View" : projectCat },
    "project" : {"View" : projectName }
};

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();

function projectCat(ctx) {
    var output = [];
    var field = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];

    if (field.length > 0) {
        var lookupValue = field[0].lookupValue;
    }
        output.push(lookupValue);
        return output.join('');
}

function projectName(ctx) {
    var output = [];
    var field = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];

    if (field.length > 0) {
        var lookupValue = field[0].lookupValue;
    }

        output.push(lookupValue);
        return output.join('');
}
```

Comment: It seems like the context object is null / undefined.

Comment: ..yeah I understand that from the error message;  just not sure why since I thought I defined it in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Realized I forgot to call the function on the current item `(ctx).  projectName(ctx);` worked fine.